# How to cache AngularJs *.js files

Tags: angularjs, caching, angularjs-routing, web-optimization

I'm building quite big Angular application. I have some problems with caching `*.js` files. Every time route is changed, all `*.js` files are downloaded.

[image]

I know I should join all `js` files and minimize them, but first I want figure following problem.

One problem is that all requests have `?_=<rondom_number>` appended on end of URL. And I don't know how to remove that.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you loading your angular files?

Comment: @Tuvia On bottom of index.html body https://github.com/matjazmav/tpo10/blob/sprint1/index.html

Comment: It's not random number. I think It's a timestamp that using to avoid caching that added by jQuery to every request. Try this on page load: `jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: true}`

Comment: Thank you, now it is caching :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rootatdarkstar suggested I have included this line of code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
```

Loading speed is definitely better, from about ~5s to about ~300ms. Now all files are taken from cache next step is to join and minimize all `js` files in to one file.

Thanks again.